# modify Java/Scala class variables with JPype?

Tags: scala, jpype

I've been trying to use JPype to interface with Scala, and it's been going well, but I've been having trouble modifying class/object variables. To get the value out of them, you have to invoke them as a function (e.g. myObj.var() might give 5). I haven't been able to figure out how to reassign something to myObj.var, since it is of some JavaBoundMethod type or something like that. Is this possible with JPype?

Comment: This is a very good project, i have done some code on Java, do you still work on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the member has really been declared as a `var` (and not as a `val`), there should be a method named `myObj.var_$eq()` which you can invoke.

This code ...

```
class Foo {
  var i: Int = 0
}
```

... ends up like this in the bytecode:

```
scala> :javap -s Foo
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Foo {
  public int i();
  public void i_$eq(int);
  public Foo();
}
```